# create a button in activity to launch all the installed application in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a button in activity to launch all the installed application as applications launcher button on home screen open all the application.
it will be a great help with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code gives you all the installed apps. I am filtering out the apps which can be launched. If you want all the apps irrespective they can be launched or not, then you can remove the if (mIntent != null) check.

```
   List<PackageInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; apps != null && i < apps.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = apps.get(i);


        Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                p.packageName);
        if (mIntent != null) {
            PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo appInfo = null;
            try {
                appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(p.packageName, 0);
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String appName = pm.getApplicationLabel(appInfo).toString();
            Drawable appIcon = appInfo.loadIcon(getApplicationContext()
                    .getPackageManager());

        }
    }
```

Comment: It work well, a great thanks for your answer. A request from you ,actually  I m trying to create a button which can launch as applications launcher button on home screen open all the application in our mobile, for example if we launch music player by android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER which directly open our inbuilt music player.